# Create Vectors Instead of Columns for Table() or Tibble() for Vector by Row Word Occurrence Table r

Tags: r, string, vector

I have a vector with ~30,000 strings as elements (roughly 30 characters each).  Here is an example:

```
OriginalVector <- c("nimble red fox", "lazy grey dog", "red fox funny")
```

I need a method to convert these strings into word occurrence tables.  Where the occurrence of a given word within an element is signified with a 1 (or other integer).  This information needs to be cross referenced against each other string in the vector.

Solution 1:

```
table(unnest_tokens(df, word, text))
```

Output Solution 1:

```
id  dog fox funny grey lazy nimble red
  1   0   1     0    0    0      1   1
  2   1   0     0    1    1      0   0
  3   0   1     1    0    0      0   1
```

Solution 2:

```
df %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
  count(id, word) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = word, 
              values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  select(-id)
```

Output Solution 2:

```
    fox nimble   red   dog  grey  lazy funny
  <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1      1     1     0     0     0     0
2     0      0     0     1     1     1     0
3     1      0     1     0     0     0     1
```

Unfortunately I need vectors in place of columns.  Such that:

```
fox <- c(1, 0, 1)
nimble <- c(1, 0, 0)
```

Is there a way do this for Solution 1 or Solution 2? Preferably Solution 1 as it is less resource intensive.

Comment: If you have a data.frame, based on the column names, it can be extracted with `$` or `[[` or convert to a list `asplit(out, 2) %>% list2env(.GlobalEnv)` not recommended though

Comment: Specify the package containing `unnest_tokens` (? `tidytext`) and include `df``.